# Partial Application Macro in Rust, Works But

Tags: rust, macros, currying, partial-application

So I was writing (attempting) some variadic macros to try to implement compose and curry in rust. `pipe` was easy enough.
Variadic partial application though? Not so much. Props to anyone who can come up with a solution for this partial application macro that doesn't use those pesky seemingly ignorable type args (and maybe variadic? w/o reflection I think it's impossible):

```rust
    //ltr compose for closures
macro_rules! pipe {
    ($init:tt |> $($fn:ident),+) => {{
        let mut r = $init;
        $( r = $fn(r); )*
        r
    }}
}

//partially apply a closure w/ up to 4 args
macro_rules! apply {
    ($fn:ident<$t1:ty,$t2:ty>($arg1:expr)) => {
        |x:$t2| $fn($arg1 as $t1, x)
    };
    ($fn:ident<$t1:ty,$t2:ty,$t3:ty>($arg1:expr)) => {
        |x:$t2, y:$t3| $fn($arg1 as $t1,x, y)
    };
    ($fn:ident<$t1:ty,$t2:ty,$t3:ty>($arg1:expr, $arg2:expr)) => {
        |x:$t3| $fn($arg1 as $t1,$arg2 as $t2,x)
    };
    ($fn:ident<$t1:ty,$t2:ty,$t3:ty,$t4:ty>($arg1:expr)) => {
        |x: $t2, y:$t3, z:$t4| $fn($arg1 as $t1, x, y, z)
    };
    ($fn:ident<$t1:ty,$t2:ty,$t3:ty,$t4:ty>($arg1:expr, $arg2:expr)) => {
        |x:$t3, y:$t4| $fn($arg1 as $t1,$arg2 as $t2, x, y)
    };
    ($fn:ident<$t1:ty,$t2:ty,$t3:ty,$t4:ty>($arg1:expr, $arg2:expr, $arg3:expr)) => {
        |x:$t4| $fn($arg1 as $t1,$arg2 as $t2,arg3 as $t3,x)
    };
}

fn main() {
    
 
    let add = |x:i32, y:i32| x + y;
    let sq = |x:i32| x * x;
    let dbl = |x:i32| x * 2;
    //blargh i hate those typeargs! i need them for the matcher
    //to get the original params number and type since rust has no reflection :(
    //weirdly if i ignore them with _ it works. But it will luckily fail
    //hard if you supply incorrect args.
    let plus1 = apply!(add<_,_>(1));
    
    let r = pipe!(3 |> dbl, plus1, sq);
    
    print!("{}", r);
}
```

Edit: The reason I seemingly cannot do variadic args on this is because that changes the structure of the closure. Seemed fine at first glance, I'd just wrap it in a match statement based on the total params and difference between the number of exprs vs total params. but if you try to return closures of varying signatures in a match arm it won't compile. The good news is this approach is probably low-overhead. But its really not a great improvement over partial application thru inline closures as necessary:

```rust
//simple, works, no type args or even type declarations on params I'm just a crazy person who wants it all!
let add = |x, y| x + y;
let add1 = |x| add(x, 1);
```

So its really just an academic pursuit at this point, it hardly seems practical

Comment: Hi there! Maybe I'm missing something, but, uhm, what is the question exactly? Is it just that you are asking if/how you can rid of those "type args"?

Comment: I suppose I should've been a bit more clear. I want to primarily get rid of those type args yes, just so my implementation doesn't need them. But I was also wondering if there was a way to express this variadically. Rarely do i want to curry a function with more than 4 args but maybe I do and then to use my current implementation I'll need to add (args-1) worth of patterns per number of original arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether or not I understand your question, but I think maybe this library may help you: https://docs.rs/partial_application/0.2.0/partial_application/

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate partial_application;

//ltr compose for closures
macro_rules! pipe {
    ($init:tt |> $($fn:ident),+) => {{
        let mut r = $init;
        $( r = $fn(r); )*
        r
    }}
}

fn main() {


    let add = |x:i32, y:i32| x + y;
    let sq = |x:i32| x * x;
    let dbl = |x:i32| x * 2;
    //blargh i hate those typeargs! i need them for the matcher
    //to get the original params number and type since rust has no reflection :(
    //weirdly if i ignore them with _ it works. But it will luckily fail
    //hard if you supply incorrect args.
    let plus1 = partial!(add => 1,_);
    let r = pipe!(3 |> dbl, plus1, sq);

    print!("{}", r);
}
```

You may refer to this library to create your own macro.